What is the solution of npx firequiz error?
When I write
npx firequiz
I get this error:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/isPlainObject'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Rapid Computer's\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\aab6981678745c7e\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js
- C:\Users\Rapid Computer's\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\aab6981678745c7e\node_modules\inquirer\lib\inquirer.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rapid Computer's\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\aab6981678745c7e\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\prompt.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    "C:\\Users\\Rapid Computer's\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\aab6981678745c7e\\node_modules\\inquirer\\lib\\ui\\prompt.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Rapid Computer's\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\aab6981678745c7e\\node_modules\\inquirer\\lib\\inquirer.js"
  ]
}


What is my issue and how do I solve it?

It could be linked to this, it may be related to changes in the lodash library. You may need to install a specific version of lodash in order to resolve your issue
